# Access is denied при вызове SetParent() в WIN10

Tags: c#

Добрый день!
Есть задача найти окно в WINDOWS, и данное окно прикрепить к UI (WPF). 
Я использую уже рабочую библиотеку , которая работала под WIN7. 
Сейчас я пишу под WIN10 и получаю ошибку.

Есть код:

```
 [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern IntPtr SetParent(IntPtr hwndChild, IntPtr hwndNewParent);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    public static extern bool SetWindowPos(IntPtr hwnd, IntPtr hwndInsertAfter, int x, int y, int cx, int cy, SetWindowPosFlags uFlags);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern int SetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex, int dwNewLong);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    public static extern bool MoveWindow(IntPtr hwnd, int x, int y, int width, int height, bool repaint);
    m_hwnd = FindWindow(null, ExternalWindowName);
    if (m_hwnd == (IntPtr)0)
                return;

    IntPtr prn = SetParent(m_hwnd, this.Handle);
   //prn == 0
   // GetLastError() возырвщает код ошибки 5..
```

В чем может быть дело?

Спасибо..

Comment: если вы имеете в виду вызов SetParent для окна из другого процесса, это не поддерживаемый режим который обычно не рекомендуется использовать. тем более в сочетании с WPF, это вообще изврат.  на самом деле, ранее в документации по функции SetParent было замечание, что так делать не рекомендуется, но потом его почему-то убрали. в Windows 10 скорее всего ужесточили ограничения по доступу к чужим окнам, поэтому и перестало работать. если приложение запускать с повышенными привелегиями, тоже не работает?